# Batch version of sessionization-like counting in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've got log files from various devices showing users and want to create kind of a stateful count of users visiting specfic websites for every minute. I can tranform the data to a format: `ts,websitename,userID,(-)1` (1 for joiners/-1 for leavers).

I'd like to end up with a time series with count per website per ts:

```
ts1,siteA,34
ts2,siteA,30 <- 4 users left
ts3,siteA,32 <- 2 users joined
```

The way to do this in Spark streaming is well descibed. The most straight-forward way IMHO would be to have a timewindow in Spark Streaming of the desired aggregation time and use updateStateByKey to keep a count per website (not even taking into account log ts to keep it simple).

Now the question is how to achieve this in a batch process, more specifically it's not to hard to use `aggregateByKey()` and end up with something like:

```
ts0,siteA,30
ts1,siteA,4
ts2,siteA,-4
ts3,siteA,2
```

But then how to iterate over that? It would not sound very logical but the only thing I can think of would be to sort the data using `sortByKey()`, partition it to be sure that all data for a specific site is on one node, and then iterate over every element of the RDD creating a new RDD with (ts,count)..

But e.g. using foreach doesn't iterate over the elements sequentially as far as I understand. Actually this might not even suit Spark well as it's not really "batch-type" work going down to the level of individual records.

Any help or pointers to specific functions greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's the end result you're aiming for?  `siteX, fromT, toT, count`?

Comment: I'd like to end up with ts,site,active_count (as specified in the first grey block, that is the end result aim) - to visualize the amount of active users in a time series dashboard.